# Tomcat, Microsoft JDBC 4, Linux and integrated security

Tags: linux, jdbc, tomcat7, integrated-security

I currently have Tomcat 7 running Java spring services on windows server 2008.  Tomcat is running under a windows account that has access to our SQL Server Databases.  We are using Microsoft SQL JDBC 4 (sqljdbc4.jar) with integrated security to access the SQL Server Databases (always using the Tomcat account).

I am trying to set up the same process on a linux server (Ubuntu Server).  I know that the sqljdbc4.jar allows for SSO with windows active directy via pure Java Kerberos.  However, the little documentation I can find show authenticating the client for access.

Our services is used with mobile clients that aren't part of our active directory (website and iOS apps).  Is it possible to use the pure Java Kerberos with sqljdbc4 and the tomcat user (linux user authenticated through our Active Directory) on instead of the client?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this issue

Comment: I think I have the same problem -- was there any update on this?